# Cannot access USB with Virtualbox 6.1.32 r149290 on 20.04 host

Tags: 20.04, usb, virtualbox

I came across this problem before. The workarounds below used to work. But it just doesn't work this time.

Basically, I have tried to [modify](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=59462#p353730) vboxdrv.rule

and

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

but none of them works.

I think it probably has nothing to do with permission since

```
sudo VBoxManage list usbhost
```

returns none as well

And

```
sudo lsusb
```

doesn't return anything suspicious though

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0328 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b61e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 056a:5145 Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Anyone has come across this before? I want to diagnose it somehow but I don't know where to start. Any log can I check when VirtualBox guests can't access USB?

Comment: After you added yourself to the `vboxusers` group, did you log out and back in or reboot?

Comment: yes. I did. I rebooted several times but to no avail.

Comment: +1 for visibility.  Hmmm, I am not sure.  Last thought is possibly missing the Extensions Pack.  I have the same version installed and the same OS but all my USB devices are showing up.  If you have it installed, hopefully someone else might have experienced the same thing and will be able to help.  I am sorry that I am not much more help from here.

Comment: yes, i installed extension pack as well. i checked under preference and it is showing the same version as virtualbox. Sorry for forgetting to mention that.

Comment: Did you make sure to select USB 3.0 in VirtualBox's settings for the VM?

Comment: Yes. USB 3.0 is selected

Answer (score 0):

virtualbox > settings > system > motherboard > chipset: ICH9
it works for me.
I hope it is helpful for you too.

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion. however, it seems to be something else. I have two more machines and don't have any problems like that before. I start to think if hardware could be an issue. But the laptop seems fine except the touchscreen is not working properly.